# Change input value before form submit on angular's directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that applies a number mask to text inputs. So, I have inputs with values like this: **999.999.999**. My problem is that I want to change this value to **999999999** before submit the form to send "clean" values to server side. The question is: **How can I do this inside mi directive?**

I tried to use the following code inside my link function but, I'm a little bit lost.

```
$(_element).parents('form').submit( function() {
    //I don't know how to change the input value here...
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(_element).parents('form').submit( function() {
  $('input').val().replace('.', ''); 
  return true;
});
```

This will replace the value of the input, the value to replace will be `.` and the value to be replaced with would be nothing. So you'll get the desired answer!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you'll need to get+set the value of the element, using (for example) a simple RegEx to remove the dots:

```
var enteredValue = $(_element).val();
$(_element).val(enteredValue.replace(/\./g,''));
```

However, it might be a good idea to integrate with Angular's form handling, that has a number of hooks in to handle validation and processing of inputs in this way. Specifically, working with Angular's [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController)'s $parsers, that processes the values entered by the user, and only ever allows the "good" values into the model in the scope. You can probably do this in your existing custom directive, or a separate one as below:

```
app.directive('cleanNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return val.replace(/\./g,'');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Which you can use as an attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="number" ng-model="number" clean-number />
```

You can then call a function to submit the form using the ngSubmit directive:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
  ...
  <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

And then the processed value is available in the scope as `$scope.number`. You can see this in action in [my plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CtFKsjAuzQHquBVSesp8?p=preview).